# How to achieve this halftone-like background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

Attached is an image with a distinctive comic books style background. How would you achive that for a large project on Illustrator?

[image: img]

Comment: What have you tried, and what were the problems you encountered?

Answer (score 2):

There are default patterns included with Illustrator.

`Swatch Panel Menu > Open Library > Pattern > Basic Graphics > Basic_Graphics_Dots`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the result must be sharp, but the dark dots must be like 45 degrees rotated rounded squares rather than sharp ones or circles.

You have already got a suggestion to use a fill pattern which is obviously needed to keep the object count acceptable. Another way is to tile symbols. Too many, say 10000 independent shapes can slow down the computer.

Here's one version:

[image]

1. There's a square and a darker smaller square with rounded corners, it's rotated 45 degrees. To keep calculations lighter expand the appearance of the rotated square (=fix the effects). The dimensions are not critical, only be sure that the dark dots are not too big. Dimensions here: 3x3 millimeters and 2x2 millimeters.
2. Place the rotated square to the bottom right corner of the bigger square. It snaps easily if you have Smart Guides and Snap to Point =ON. Tile carefully squares as shown to make a tileable fill pattern. Combine the bigger squares with Pathfinder Panel Unite.

Drag the pattern to the swatches collection. Fill a big area with it and see the result:

[image]

Before dragging the pattern to the Swatches scale it to the wanted size. This is a smaller version:

[image]

Comment: One can rotate patterns irrespective of shape which makes designing the pattern even easier.